# MySQL Create View failing when run from a script

Tags: mysql, sql, view

first time poster. I'm having trouble getting a couple create view queries to run from a .sql file properly. I've tested the following queries on the school server and they work fine, except when run using the 'source' command.

***EDIT**: I've tried running this two different ways `source ~/file_location/file_name.sql` from the command line and it'll pull the file fine, but nothing seems to execute. And I've also tried running it straight at the sql server login with `< ~/file_location/file_name.sql`

***EDIT 2**: Now showing USE statement for which database the file should be directed to, previously unmentioned but was present at the time of this question being posed.

```
USE [database]    

CREATE VIEW Country_View AS
        SELECT Name, Code, Continent, Population
        FROM Country;

CREATE VIEW city_country_view AS 
    SELECT City.Name, City.Population, Country.Name, Country.Population
    FROM City, Country
    WHERE City.Country = Country.Code;

CREATE VIEW city_country_view2 AS
    SELECT City.Name, City.Population, Country.Name, Country.Population
    FROM City LEFT JOIN Country ON City.Country = Country.Code
    WHERE Country.Code = "USA" OR Country.Code = "CAN" OR Country.Code = "MEX";

CREATE VIEW country_language_view AS
    SELECT Country.Name, Country.Continent, Country.Region, CountryLanguage.Language
    FROM Country, CountryLanguage
    WHERE Country.Code = CountryLanguage.Country;

CREATE VIEW country_language_view2 AS
    SELECT Country.Name, Country.Continent, Country.Region, CountryLanguage.Language
    FROM Country LEFT JOIN CountryLanguage ON Country.Code = CountryLanguage.Country
    WHERE Language = "English" AND IsOfficial = "T";
```

Again, executing them directly from the command line works, but importing them is neither throwing errors nor creating the view(s). MySQL version is 5.7.19 I believe.

Comment: Please mention how you are importing the .sql file.

Comment: I've tried running this two different ways 'source ~/file_location/file_name.sql' from the command line and it'll pull the file fine, but nothing seems to execute. And I've also tried running it straight at the sql server login with '< ~/file_location/file_name.sql'

I've updated the original question with this info.

Comment: Check your default database. Try to add DB name to each viewname and tablename.

Comment: @Akina are you referring to a USE [database] statement? Because I do have one of those before any of the code, it's just not shown alongside my statements at the time of this reply (I'll update the question). Or is there a method to clarify a specific database per query?

Comment: Yes, you may try to add USE command as the most first command in the batch. As a palliative. But specifying the database in [client] of my.ini and complete names specifying is more correct. *importing them is neither throwing errors nor the creating view(s)* Does error log is empty? Does specifying these batch commands in CLI command line or executing directly causes an error message? is your batch file accessible in the filesystem for client and server processes?

Comment: @Akina, I double checked the queries by running them directly seems I missed an error from the second and third stating that duplicate fields were present [Name, Population], I have since fixed this by appending an AS statement for these instances. Direct query now runs, but still wouldn't run when imported. Turns out it was a me issue where the file wasn't saved to the proper location, thus, I was importing a blank batch file instead of my queries.
Chalk another one up to ID-10-T error...

Comment: Note that queries against views cannot utilise underlying indexes in MySQL, rendering them of limited value.